# Angular 6 ngbTypeahead filter of list of JSON objects

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

I've got a ngbTypeahead which when typing in the field should be able to query a list of objects.  The formate of the objects in the list "projections" is

```
{
    code: "6326"
    group: "world"
    name: "WGS 1984"
}
```

HTML :

```
<input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.outputProjection.name" [ngbTypeahead]="search" />
```

search filter code in component.ts class :

```
    search = (text$: Observable < string > ) =>
    text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        merge(this.focus$),
        map(term => (term === '' ? this.projections :
            this.projections.filter(v => v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
    )
```

When I type into the typeahead what I get is :

[image]

But what I would like to show up is the name in the json object.....

Also as a sidenote the folks at bootstrap closed this and said it's not a bug but a feature request:

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/749

Most modern UI Controls work with objects regardless of platform.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add formatter to your code

```
formatter = (result: string) => result.name;
```

also, include formatter to the template.

```
<input id="typeahead-format" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultFormatter]="formatter" />
```

Comment: I actually tried using that from https://stackblitz.com/edit/autofill-from-object-typescriptangular-5-mjduzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts and sadly still didn't work and it overrides the ngModel

Comment: Also the items in the filter still appear as Objects.

Comment: @yamamoto585 you might also want to use [inputFormatter]

Comment: @shajan I think the result type in your formatter shoud be any, not string

Comment: @AlexC you can use string or any based on your requirement.

Comment: I had to change the type inside the formatter to the object I was checking against for it to return the correct value rather than [Object] [Object]

Comment: @shajan How to limit the result to maximum 10 records or match result to exact search term ? I am getting matched records at top and rest all records (which dont match) below that , making my page scrollable

Comment: @ChetanBirajdar I believe the result is already limited to 10 records. But you can use startsWith to reduce the matched results. use this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvy38x

Comment: @shajan the formatter needs to be changed to access and object property as per salmans answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please add formatter and as you are using object as data source for that you need to  **descontruct** your object to get desired fields:

```
formatter = (x: {name: string}) => x.name;
```

HTML input element need one more attribute [inputFormatter]

```
<input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.outputProjection.name" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [inputFormatter]="formatter" />
```

Comment: this already has an accepted answer in fact you copied it exactly. ‍♂️